# How to get a Keynote presentation to display in a PWA?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, keynote

I have a strange scenario in which I’d like to have a Keynote presentation appear inside a PWA, running as it usually would in the Keynote app, but without the option to pinch out. I’ve tried a few niche forums on the problem, most of which seem to link back to http://www.keynoteiframe.com. This seems like a great tool, if it weren’t for the fact that the `#embed=true` tag it sets in the URL doesn’t seem to work, and all the iframe does when I open my app is open Keynote to the iCloud document, beating the purpose of a PWA entirely. Important to mention is the fact that I need the “links only” presentation type I’ve set to work.

I don’t want to go through setting up a server, so I’m using a data URL followed by the `<meta>` tag for a web app. Crazily enough, this works, and I can have a web app that’s not on the web.